# Catch/Listen Close Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Is there a way to Catch/Listen to the flash player close in the swf?
something like close event in air?

this swf will run as a standalone, not in a browser.

Hacks are more then welcome...

Comment: Is this in the context of SWF embedded in a web page (I mean, in a browser?)

Comment: no, running in Flash Pro CS3-5, as an extension panel.

Answer (score 0):

Not explicitly.  But you can make use of the browser's [onUnload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) event to call a function inside your SWF using JavaScript via [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: should of mentioned it, it needs to run as a standalone. thanks for the try though

Comment: Then no; there is nothing you can do.  Unless something is in the SDK used for extending Flash Pro.